# Implementing Trending Topics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, trending

I'm currently in the way of implementing Trending Topics to my Rails application.

What I currently have is this:

Each post has `topic` attribute of 2 to 3 words describing its topic.

Then I get the top posts by their view count (I have also likes & favorites available, but for the time being using simply views):

```
def trending_topics
  Post.order("COALESCE(impressions_count, 0) DESC").limit(200)
end
```

And then what I do is to simply choose only unique topics and display a number of them:

```
  <% trending_topics.select(:topic).map(&:topic).uniq.take(10).each do |topic| %>
      <li><%= topic %></li>
  <% end %>
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to get most frequently appearing `:topic`, rank them,
   and pick the cream of the crop of those?
2. Is this a sustainable way to keep track of popular topics? If not,
   is there a way to make it more efficient?
3. Is there a better way to implement a function that searches for the
   most popular and frequent `:topic` attributes in posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

**(1)**  Yes, you can get a hash with the frequency of each `:topic` like so:

```
array = trending_topics.select(:topic).map(&:topic)
freq = array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
# => {'topic1'=>3, 'topic2'=>3, 'topic3'=>1, ...}
```

**(2)**  This is "sustainable" in the sense that it does not grow in complexity as the number of posts/topics you introduce is increased (because you are still sampling from the top 200 posts, though getting the "top 200" will take slightly more compute time as the number of posts grows).

**(3)**  I would think that `impressions_count` would not be a very good way to keep track of what is trending, since to me `impressions_count` has the total number of impressions, while you want some temporal aspect of it (e.g. `impressions_this_week`).

So one way to do it would be to introduce an `impressions_this_week` column that is updated at regular intervals.  Then you can choose based on that.

Another way would be to write a method that uses the overall `impressions_count` along with the `created_at` or `updated_at` timestamp to calculate how "hot" the post is.  You could do this with a simple decay function and then tweak the constants of that function until you get the decay that you want.  There is something similar to this concept shown here: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/12/Most-popular-metrics-in-App-Engine.  Once you have that method written, you can just sort based on its output.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something a bit more sophisticated than your current ranking algorithm you should probably have a look at [how sites like reddit](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588) and [hackernews](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574) handle this issue. It is fairly complicated but you should be able to find an implementation of each algorithm in Ruby if you google it.